# Django/Python: Raw SQL Query - Error binding parameter

Tags: python, django

I'm having a hard time figuring why I'm receiving the below error when the SQL I'm aiming for seems valid. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
```

Here's my raw SQL query in question:

```
entries = Entry.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM learning_logs_entry LEFT JOIN learning_logs_document ON (learning_logs_entry.id = learning_logs_document.entry_id) WHERE learning_logs_entry.topic_id = %s AND learning_logs_entry.tag_id IN %s ORDER BY learning_logs_entry.date_added DESC", params=[topic_id, (1,2,3)])
```

Here's the SQL query produced:

```
SELECT * FROM learning_logs_entry LEFT JOIN learning_logs_document ON (learning_logs_entry.id = learning_logs_document.entry_id) WHERE learning_logs_entry.topic_id = 1 AND learning_logs_entry.tag_id IN (1, 2, 3) ORDER BY learning_logs_entry.date_added DESC
```

Here's my model for both Entry & Tag:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='entries') 
    text = models.TextField(validators=[validate_text])
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta: #metadata
        verbose_name_plural = 'entries'

class Tag(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.ImageField(upload_to='files/', blank=True, null=True)
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Comment: Why do you use a raw SQL query in the first place? THis can be effective done with the Django ORM.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Honestly, I wanted to, but I couldn't get the results I wanted (probably due to my inexperience). I couldn't figure out how to retrieve all entries for a topic while getting any related documents (some entries have some, while others didn't) so I resorted to a raw SQL after my failed attempts.

Comment: can you share the relevant part of the `Document` model (probably with a `ForeignKey` to the `Entry` model)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I updated the original post with the Document model, but you're right. There's a ForeignKey to Entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not make use of raw queries, unless it is something that can not be done (efficiently) with the Django ORM.

This however *can* be done effectively with the Django ORM, for example with:

```
Entry.objects.filter(
    tag_id__in=[1,2,3]
    topic_id=topic_id    
).prefetch_related('document_set').order_by('-date_added')
```

The `.prefetch_related` will make an extra query, but this will reduce the amount of bandwidth, since if this is done in a JOIN, the same record of entry can be returned multiple times, that could result in transmitting the same data *hundreds* of times.

Comment: I tried using ORM like you suggested and it's getting all the criteria correctly except for the Document. Am I missing something in my model? Here's the SQL that is generated from the ORM.


`SELECT "learning_logs_entry"."id", "learning_logs_entry"."topic_id", "learning_logs_entry"."text", "learning_logs_entry"."date_added", "learning_logs_entry"."tag_id", "learning_logs_entry"."user_id" FROM "learning_logs_entry" WHERE ("learning_logs_entry"."tag_i
d" IN (1, 2, 3) AND "learning_logs_entry"."topic_id" = 1) ORDER BY "learning_logs_entry"."date_added" DESC`

Comment: @Fys: well as said, Django's ORM prevents such `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, because it can result in *gigantic* result tables with lots of duplicate data. What we do with `.prefetch_related` is first obtain all the `Entry` objects we need, and then in a second query fetch *all* documents related to at least one of these `Entry`s, and then finally do the JOINing at the Django/Python level. This is often more efficient. You can thus access the documents with `myentry.document_set.all()`, and the `.prefetch_related` will fetch all these elements in *bulk*.

Comment: @Fys: for more information, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related